# fprintf nested in for loop does not write the first element

Tags: c, printf

## Description

I am trying to write a csv table, `tablepath`, and I need to include in it the name of the variables, which are in a text file, `filepath`. I am using a first function, `read_par`, to retrieve the names from `filepath` and a second function, `store`, to write in the table.

## Problem

**The table created is systematically missing the name of the first variable from the text file**. The `read_par` function is functional and produces the expected output: a string containing the name of the variable, I also included it for context.

#### `filepath`

- Here is the structure of the text file:

`par1
0 1 0.5
par2
1 1 1
par3
0 1 1
par4
0 1 1
par5
0 1 1
par6
0 1 1`

#### `store`

- Here is the `store` function:

  ```
  int store(int par_num, float sim_num, float **tab_param, char *filepath, char *tablepath){

  int j;
  char *name = NULL;
  FILE* sim_table = NULL;
  sim_table = fopen(tablepath, "w");  

  // Start the first line in the table
  fprintf(sim_table,"simulation_number");

  for(j=1; j < par_num+1; j++){

      // If it is the last parameter -> create a new line
      if(j == par_num){

          name = read_name(j, filepath);
          fprintf(sim_table,",%s\n", name);
      }else{
          /* If it is not the last parameter -> continue writing on 
           * the same line */
          name = read_name(j, filepath);
          fprintf(sim_table,",%s", name);
      }
  }
  fclose(sim_table);
  return 0;
  }
  ```

#### `read_name`

- Here is the `read_name` function:

  ```
  char *strtok(char *line, char *eof);    

  char *read_name(int par_id, char *filepath){

  char *par_name;
  int count = 0;

  FILE *file = fopen(filepath, "r");

  if ( file != NULL ){

      char line[256]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
      while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL){ /* read a line */

          if (count == (2*par_id)-2){

              // strtok removes the \n character from the string line
              strtok(line, "\n");
              par_name = line;

              fclose(file);
          }
          else{
              count++;
          }
      }
  }
  else
  {
      printf("\n\n ERROR IN FUNCTION READ_PAR\n\nTEXT FILE IS EMPTY\n\n");
  }
  return par_name;
  }
  ```

#### `tablepath`

The table I am obtaining looks like this:

```
┌─────────────────┬┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┐
│simulation_number││par2│par3│par4│par5│par6│
└─────────────────┴┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┘
```

With the `par1` name missing, but all the other variable name successfully printed. I do not know where is the problem. Is it a problem in the for loop conditions or something to do with the `par1` string itself?

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: One problem is that `read_name` returns the address of `line`. `line` is a local variable which goes out of scope (ceases to exist) at the end of the function.

Comment: @user3386109 I do not understand your comment. The `read_name` function does indeed returns the address of a string, but I tested this part of the code and it is functional. The fact that the names `par2` to `par6` are present in the table proves it, but could the problem you are mentioning explain somehow why the first element, `par1` is not being written to the table?

Comment: Yup, the worst thing about [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984) in C is that sometimes the code appears to work, even when it is technically incorrect. And by technically incorrect, I mean that the code *will* break at some point. For example, if you add another function call between the call to `read_name` and the call to `fprintf`, there's a good chance that `name` will be corrupted, and won't print properly.

Comment: OTOH, it's not immediately obvious how that would explain `par1` failing and `par2` to `par6` succeeding. A quick test is to declare `line` with the `static` keyword: `static char line[256]`. Give that a try and let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Thanks [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) declaring `line` as a `static char` did solve the problem! Could you format your comment as an answer for future references?

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that worked! You just learned a very important lesson about C programming. Just because a program seems to work (for a simple test) doesn't mean it's actually correct. Beware of undefined behavior! As you gain more experience with C, it will get easier for you to spot (and avoid) undefined behavior. Sure, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `read_name` returns the address of a local variable (`line`). That local variable goes out of scope (and technically ceases to exist) when the function returns. So using the returned pointer results in [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984).

Too see the problem more clearly, here's a simplified version of `read_name` with only the relevant lines shown:

```
char *read_name(int par_id, char *filepath){

    char *par_name;

        char line[256];             // line is a local variable
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL){

                par_name = line;    // par_name now points to the local variable
        }
    }
    return par_name;                // returning the address of the local variable
}
```

It was noted in the comments under the question that `read_name` was tested and was found to be functional. So how can it be wrong? That's the worst thing about undefined behavior in C. Sometimes the code appears to work during testing even though it is technically incorrect. And by technically incorrect, I mean that it *will* break at some point. For example, in the `store` function, if you add another function call between the call to `read_name` and the call to `fprintf`, there's a good chance that `name` will be corrupted, and won't print properly.

An easy solution in this case is to declare `line` with the `static` keyword:

```
static char line[256];
```

That way, `line` has static storage duration, which means it will continue to exist after `read_name` returns.